# Deleting several links in a complete directed weighted graph of turtles

Tags: netlogo

I have n turtles which all have links with one another. That means I posses a complete directed weighted graph. I've managed to locate the links with maximum value per each turtle, but now I want to delete all other links without maximum value, again per each turtle.
I'm using the **[die]** function but in order to distinguish the set of links per each turtle and then clear links from each set
This is the line of code I'm using:

```
> ask turtles 
      [ 
>     ask my-in-links with [trust < max [trust] of links with [other-end] =  ] [die]  
      ]
```

However, I thought instead of using other-end function I could also use this line of code

```
> ask turtles [
ask my-in-links with [trust < max [trust] of links with [out-link-to] =  ] [die]
]
```

My initial thought was by using one of the two functions (other-end/ out-link-to), I could create a common attribute between the set of links. 
My main problem is

1. I'm not sure whether the functions (other-end/ out-link-to) are correct
2. I don't know what to write after the "=" expression
3. I don't know which turtle the ask turtle function begins to work with

Comment: The answer to (3) is that `ask` goes through the turtles in a random order. Can you please clarify whether you are trying to (A) For each pair of turtles there are two links (one in each direction) and you want to keep whichever has the higher trust? or (B) For each turtle, you want to keep the in-link (or out-link) that has the highest trust value and delete links to all the other turtles. With 10 turtles, option A would leave you with 45 links and option B would leave you with 10 links.

Comment: my goal is option B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete model that does what you are trying to achieve.

```
links-own [trust]

to testme
  clear-all
  ; create complete directed network
  create-turtles 10
  ask turtles
  [ create-links-to other turtles
    [ set trust random 50
    ]
  ]
  ; display complete network briefly
  layout-circle turtles 10
  type "average trust value is: " print mean [trust] of links
  wait 5
  ; delete all except highest trust for each turtle
  ask turtles
  [ let keeper my-in-links with-max [trust]
    ask my-in-links with [not member? self keeper][die]
  ]
  type "average trust value is: " print mean [trust] of links
end
```

I have it showing the initial network and printing average trust values so you can see what's going on.

The important concept here is that `my-links` is an agentset (in particular, it's a linkset because the agents in the set are links). Since what you're trying to do is just look through the links that are connected to one turtle, then it doesn't matter which turtles are at the other end and you don't need to refer to the other end at all.

You can simply look at the set of links that attach to the particular turtle (`my-in-links` or `my-links` or `my-out-links`) and then look at the values of trust for those links. I have used `with-max` to find the one with the highest value and then used set membership. But you could also use

```
  ask turtles
  [ let upper max [trust] of my-in-links
    ask my-in-links with [trust < upper] [die]
  ]
```

which is closest to the code you wrote in your question.